# Open urls in BlueJ

Tags: java, url, bluej

is it possible to open urls in BlueJ.
For example in PHP I can use the function file_get_contents()

Is there something equal in BlueJ?

Comment: BlueJ is just an IDE, the language you're programming in is Java.

Comment: Have a look at => http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at using a buffered reader and using the URL object in Java.

It's basically something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String input = "";
while((input = reader.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```